Sidebar drops to the bottom of the page whenever it isn't in fixed position
I want my sidebar to be positioned to the left from the main block and the header, so that when the size of the window changes, all blocks move together, however, whenever I change its position from fixed to relative/sticky, it drops to the bottom of the page.
Alternatively, the sidebar could stay fixed, but I need to find a way to stop other blocks from going under it when window size changes.
html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel ="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <title>Homepage</title></head>
    
    <body>
    
        <div class="header"><div class="element" style="display: flex;"><div class="container">
            <button class="button" >1</button>
            <button class="button" >2</button>
            <button class="button" >3</button>
        </div></div></div>
        <div class="main"><div class="element">
            <h1>TestText</h1>
            <p>TestText</p>
            <h1>TestText!</h1>
        </div></div>
        <div class="sidebar"><div class="element"><div class="container"> 
        <p>TestText</p>
            <a   href="about.html" target="_blank" title="click here~" >
                <button class="button">!</button>
            </a>
            <p><button class="button">!!</button></p>
            <p><button class="button">!!!</button></p>
        </div></div></div>
    </body>
</html>

css
body {background-color: #1c1f2b;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        min-height: 100vh;
        font-family: Humaroid;
        srs:url(/fonts/Humaroid.otf) format("opentype");
        font-size: 1.25rem;
        word-break: break-all;}
.container{margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            position: center;}   

.sidebar {
  color: #FED2C7;
  text-shadow:
   -1px -1px 0 #704935,  
    1px -1px 0 #704935,
    -1px 1px 0 #704935,
     1px 1px 0 #704935;
    height: 100%;
    width: 160px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1; 
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-top: 20px;
    background-color: #faf4e6;
    margin-right: 20px;
    }
.header {background-color: #faf4e6;
            height: 90px;
            width: 940px;
            position: relative;
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding-bottom: 10px
            }
            
.main{ width: 940px;
        height: 80vh;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 30 px;
        background-color: #faf4e6;}
.element{
    font-weight: 400;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 1em;}

I've seen someone mentioning that this problem might be caused by div block being left open, but this doesn't seem to be the case for me.
I also tried to add bottom margin to the sidebar, but that does nothing.

Are you confusing "fixed" with "absolute". fixed will sit in the same window position while scrolling.

body {
      background-color: #1c1f2b;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      min-height: 100vh;
      font-family: Humaroid;
      srs: url(/fonts/Humaroid.otf) format("opentype");
      font-size: 1.25rem;
      word-break: break-all;
    }
    .container {
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      position: center;
    }

    .sidebar {
      color: #fed2c7;
      text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #704935, 1px -1px 0 #704935, -1px 1px 0 #704935,
        1px 1px 0 #704935;
      height: 100%;
      width: 160px;
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 1;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      padding-top: 20px;
      background-color: #faf4e6;
      margin-right: 20px;
    }
    .header {
      background-color: #faf4e6;
      height: 90px;
      width: 50%;
      position: relative;
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .main {
      width: 50%;
      height: 80vh;
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding: 30 px;
      background-color: #faf4e6;
    }
    .element {
      font-weight: 400;
      text-align: left;
      margin: 1em;
    }
    .body-element {
      margin-left: 160px;
    }

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
    <title>Homepage</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="body-element">
      <div class="header">
        <div class="element" style="display: flex">
          <div class="container">
            <button class="button">1</button>
            <button class="button">2</button>
            <button class="button">3</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="main">
        <div class="element">
          <h1>TestText</h1>
          <p>TestText</p>
          <h1>TestText!</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar">
      <div class="element">
        <div class="container">
          <p>TestText</p>
          <a href="about.html" target="_blank" title="click here~">
            <button class="button">!</button>
          </a>
          <p><button class="button">!!</button></p>
          <p><button class="button">!!!</button></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

Try this code. if it's not working well, let me know.

If you have any problem, feel free to reach out me.

Instead of trying to write custom CSS, try to refer known practices (google page grid layouts). For example, one of them would be: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp.
However, their style does not match yours, but you can try this html/css:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.item1 { grid-area: header; }
.item2 { grid-area: menu; }
.item3 { grid-area: main; }
.item5 { grid-area: footer; }

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    'menu header header header header header'
    'menu main main main main main'
    'menu footer footer footer footer footer';
  gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-container > div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Grid Layout</h1>

<p>The CSS Grid Layout Module offers a grid-based layout system, with rows and columns, making it easier to design web pages without having to use floats and positioning:</p>

<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">Header</div>
  <div class="item2">Menu</div>
  <div class="item3">Main</div>  
  <div class="item5">Footer</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>

You can achieve similar with flexbox (yet again, you may google flex page layout). Also I would recommend you to use css frameworks, like Bootstrap or Tailwind.

This is what you have using you code:

As I understand it, this is a solution



body {
    background-color: #1c1f2b;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    min-height: 100vh;
    font-family: Humaroid, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    word-break: break-all;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    justify-content: space-between;
    max-width: 940px;
}

.sidebar {
    color: #FED2C7;
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #704935, 1px -1px 0 #704935, -1px 1px 0 #704935, 1px 1px 0 #704935;
    width: 160px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    background-color: #faf4e6;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.header {
    background-color: #faf4e6;
    height: 90px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.main {
    width: calc(100% - 180px);
    height: 80vh;
    padding: 30px;
    background-color: #faf4e6;
}

.element {
    font-weight: 400;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 1em;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <title>Homepage</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="element">
                <button class="button">1</button>
                <button class="button">2</button>
                <button class="button">3</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="main">
            <div class="element">
                <h1>TestText</h1>
                <p>TestText</p>
                <h1>TestText!</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar">
            <div class="element">
                <p>TestText</p>
                <a href="about.html" target="_blank" title="click here~">
                    <button class="button">!</button>
                </a>
                <p><button class="button">!!</button></p>
                <p><button class="button">!!!</button></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>



I modified the HTML and CSS to use Flexbox for layout and ensure that the sidebar stays positioned to the left of the main block and header, even when the window size changes. Additionally, I adjusted some styles for better alignment and responsiveness keep in mind the view will look like same in different screen sizes
I hope it helps.
